# Understanding how recommender systems work for data without ratings

Tags: r, recommender-system

I am trying to build a recommender system for a supermarket and do not really have any ratings for any product apart from the number of purchases of each item. A sample of the data is like:

```
KL_ID     prod1     prod2     prod3     prod4     prod5     prod6     prod7     prod8
 1839        18         0         0         0        23         0         0         0
 1943         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  632         0         0         0         0         2         0         0        30
 4852         0         0         0         0        52         0         0         6
```

Based on this data I am trying to predict the new items each KL_ID will buy. Since I don't have any ratings, I can't do it the usual way. An alternative can be to normalize this and assume it is a rating and then use `recommenderlab`.

Comment: recommend products that people usually buy together?

Comment: you probably should google for "implicit feedback" - see here https://www.aaai.org/Papers/Workshops/1998/WS-98-08/WS98-08-021.pdf

Comment: @cory : recommend products that each KL_ID might be interested in based on previous history and comparison with other KL_IDs who purchased similar products. I hope its clear?

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to your approach, you can use [Sequential pattern mining algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_pattern_mining) if you have timestamps of purchases. Or using some [algorithm for association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) if you don't. SPMF(www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) Library has both of these types of algorithms.